# Dividing by zero with undeclared variable javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I had this task: "Use the rest parameter to create an average() function that calculates the average of an unlimited amount of numbers". And wen I ran this code, I have **0** answer.

```
function average(...nums) {
    let total = 0;
    for (const num of nums) {
        total += num;
        len = nums.length;
    }
    total = total/len;
    return total;
}
console.log(average());
```

But why? Why when I divide by the undeclared variable 0 the answer is **0** and not **NaN**? It's NaN if I run the following code (with declared variable).

```js
function average(...nums) {
  let total = 0,
    len;
  for (const num of nums) {
    total += num;
    len = nums.length;
  }
  total = total / len;
  return total;
}
console.log(average());
```

*P.s. the right answer in the task is 0.*

Comment: The code that you say returns zero throws an error for me. Please double-check if you posted the correct version of your code.

Comment: `NaN` really does sound like the right answer, as you're doing in the lower snippet. `0` is not the average of 0 numbers - 0 numbers have no average.

Comment: You first version will only work if you have run the function once with actual parameters. That is because the `len` is a global and any value it gets from one run will be available in the next if not overwritten. If you initially run the method with no arguments you will get errors about undefined `len` variable.

Comment: First snippet should throw exception `ReferenceError: len is not defined` instead of what you claimed

Comment: are you in strict mode?

Comment: It's task 16 in lesson 1 here https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud356/lessons/42383e89-ac6a-491a-b7d0-198851287bbe/concepts/6a6c5deb-2f06-4cd7-afab-222716634f10 and it is correct only with first version.

Comment: Also I found this https://repl.it/@Flaex/numbers-average-rest-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that in loose mode (i.e. not strict mode), assigning to undeclared variables makes them global.

So you run `average()` once with some arguments, which sets the global `len` to whatever number, and returns the correct average. (This is also why the udacity tests pass, the order of the tests matter. If they had run the empty input test first, it would have failed)

You then run it again with no arguments, since setting `len` happens inside the loop, it doesn't happen again because a for..of loop over an empty array doesn't even enter, so then the result of `0` (the sum) divided by `whatever` (the previous len, set to any number) will be 0.

If you had run it in strict mode, you would have gotten an error about assigning to undeclared variables, even when you run it with arguments.

This is why you always:

1. Use strict mode (add `'use strict'` to your top level function or file, if you use webpack or a similar bundler, you have this by default)
2. Declare your variables.

---

A correct version of this, assuming they want an empty input to return 0, is as follows:

```
function average(...nums) {
  'use strict'; // enter strict mode
  if (nums.length === 0) { return 0; }
  let total = 0;
  for (const num of nums) {
    total += num;
  }
  return total / nums.length;
}

console.log(average());
```

You must directly define the behavior for empty input, because strictly speaking, the average of a set of 0 numbers is undefined.